# Push object from rest api into an array Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular application, I am calling a rest-api which brings back results from the iTunes api. What I want to do is, be able to have an add button which lets me add the object(Song object) into an array, so that the user can create their own playlist. How would I push the object into an array from the rest api? My code so far for the Component.ts is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../services/api.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faRedo } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faHeadphones} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faExternalLinkAlt} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent {

  public data = [];
  public apiData: any;
  public loading = false;
  public noData = false;
  p: number = 1;
  faSearch = faSearch;
  faRedo = faRedo;
  faHeadphones = faHeadphones;
  faExternalLinkAlt = faExternalLinkAlt;
  searchQuery : string = "";

  constructor(private service: ApiService) { }

  getAll() {
    this.service.getAll(this.searchQuery).subscribe((results) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Data is received - Result - ', results);
      this.data = results.results;
      this.loading = false;

      if (this.data.length <= 0) {
        this.noData = true;
      } else if (this.data.length >= 1) {
        this.noData = false;
      } else {
        this.noData = true;
      }
    })
  }

  refresh(): void {
    window.location.reload();
  }  

  Search(){
   this.service.getAll(this.searchQuery).subscribe((results) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Data is received - Result - ', results);
      this.data = results.results;
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking on how to push an object to an array in javascript?

Comment: Its an object from a rest api, into an array

Comment: If you want results.results to be an index just do this.data.push(results.results). Also this.data.length >= 1 is an useless compare, you can just use this.data.length to check if you have at least one element in the array.

Comment: well it doesn't matter where the object comes from. If you want to push something to an array, use `push`. If you get an array from the api, assign that to a variable.

Comment: so just use `this.data.push(results.results);` and add that to a (click) function.

Comment: Yeah, basically, if `results.results` is an object, that is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the component's .ts file, you have the results of your query in the variable `songs` (which is what this.data seems to be), in the component's .html you can

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let song of songs">
    <button type="button" (click)="addSongToPlaylist(song)">Add Song {{ song.name }}</button>
</ng-container>
```

then back in the .ts file

```
addSongToPlaylist(song) {
    this.playlist.push(song);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please correct me if i am wrong, as per my understanding you want to add queried result from rest API into existing song array which is data. you can use power of spread operator here is example.

```
  Search(){
      this.service.getAll(this.searchQuery).subscribe((results) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Data is received - Result - ', results);
      this.data = [...this.data,...results.results]; // spread operator 
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Raj, but need a separate click function to push the relevant object from the rest api into an array.